# docker-compose.yml is failing due to missing file

Tags: python, docker

I have following docker-compose.yml file where i am trying to build an app but app building is failing as follows. I have following app structure with docker-compose.yml and dockerfile along with .env and Error traceback. i am using `docker-compose up --build` command

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app-name:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - APP_VAR_KEY_LIST= ${APP_VAR_KEY_LIST}
      - APP_LOG_FILE= ${APP_LOG_FILE}
```

Dokcerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8
....
COPY  . /home/app-name/
....
EXPOSE 9000
```

.env file

```
APP_VAR_KEY_LIST = ["db_password"]
APP_LOG_FILE=/home/app-name/app.log
```

project folder structure

```
├── Dockerfile
├── app.log
├── dna-common
│   ├── dna_common
├── docker-compose.yml
├── app_name
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── app_runner.py
│   ├── app_name
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── python_code_generator.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── sql
│   └── app-name-1.0.0.0.sql
├── certfile.pem
└── venv
  ......
```

Error:

```
Building app-name
[+] Building 1.4s (14/14) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 44B                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.6.8                                                  1.1s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.6.8@sha256:f20a9bfddd87c238c3d2316b4179222f219090cbb25d5b6975070d4dd4  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                0.2s
 => => transferring context: 341.22kB                                                                            0.2s
 => CACHED [7/9] COPY  . /home/app-name/                                                                         0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                           0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                          0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:2ff32ba215ca02fedb5fb3caa1c2ecb8658b889dbb2c209101deaffe6dab35b1                     0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/app-name_app-name                               0.0s
Starting app-name_app-name_1 ... done
Attaching to app-name_app-name_1
app-name_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app-name_1  |   File "/home/app-name/app_name/app_runner.py", line 4, in <module>
app-name_1  |     app = create_app_instance()
app-name_1  |   File "/home/app-name/dvmt-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/app_name-1.0.0.1-py3.6.egg/app_name/app.py", line 39, in create_app_instance
app-name_1  |     logging.basicConfig(filename=dvmt_app.config.log_file, level=logging.DEBUG)
app-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1808, in basicConfig
app-name_1  |     h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
app-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1032, in __init__
app-name_1  |     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
app-name_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
app-name_1  |     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
app-name_1  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/app-name/ /home/app-name/app.log'
app-name_app-name_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: I think you need to update your docker file COPY  . /home/app-name/ to COPY  ./app-name/

Comment: I'd guess the extra space in between `= ${...}` is causing problems.  The space is included as part of the environment variable value; then since the path name doesn't begin with `/` it's interpreted as a relative path.  That's consistent with the log message.

Comment: (In a Docker context, though, it's usually best to log to stdout, where `docker-compose logs` will be able to retrieve the log messages without worrying about a shared filesystem.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes extra space was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please add an empty app.log file as well into your directory, or do a

```
RUN touch /home/app-name/app.log
```

in your Dockerfile.

I think it cant find the supplied log file or could create one.

Also please check your .dockerignore file if you are ignoring .log files